# Moving elements with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I came across this website:
http://uploaded.net/

And i really enjoyed how they have those moving files on the left and right.
I was wondering, how does one achieve that?

**What I have tried:**

I tried just placing standard HTML images and moving the position absolutely, while it worked, there was no practical way to loop them back or make it seem...legit.... and not hacky.

Any advice or plugins i can use?

Comment: The method you described is exactly the same method that the site uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do it just as you described!

[image]

There are different ways of achieving this.

Read these articles about setInterval() and setTimeout() to understand how to make a loop in JavaScript:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Or even better, requestAnimationFrame():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

EDIT:
You told that the problem is to loop back to start, right?

You can have a setInterval function, checking every N milliseconds where is the element's "left". If it passes a point, say, 300px, reset it to 0;

something like:

```
var icon = document.getElementById("something");
var left = 0;
var speed = 1; // change this according to your taste

//... setup the image, position to absolute, etc...

setInterval(function() {
    left += speed;

    if(left >= 300) {
        left = 0;
    }
    icon.style.left = left + "px";
}, 100); //run every 0.1 seconds
```

This is a very basic example, though...

EDIT 2: handling multiples objects

There can be better approaches to it, but I would put everything inside an object and create an array of those objects, like so:

```
var MAX_LEFT = 300;

function animatedIcon(id) {
    this.left = 0;
    this.opacity = 1;
    this.speed = 3;
    this.element = document.getElementById(id);
}

var icons = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    // suposing you have the ids of your DOM elements like "icon1", "icon2", ...
    icons.push(new animatedIcon("icon"+i));
}

//You may want to tweek specific elements start position, speed or opacity, so icon can start from a different position
icons[2].left = 200;
icons[7].left = 17;
//...

setInterval(function() {
    for(i in icons) {
        icons[i].left += icons[i].speed;
        icons[i].opacity -= 0.01;
    }

    if(icons[i].left >= MAX_LEFT) {
        icons[i].left = 0;
        icons[i].opacity = 1;
    }

    icons[i].element.style.left = icons[i].left + "px";
    icons[i].element.opacity = icons[i].opacity;
}, 1000/60); //a basic "60 frames per second" rate.
```

Comment: can you mabey remove your current answer and just edit in a solution in code?

Comment: added a basic example in the answer!

Comment: Okay will check in 5-10 mins

Comment: Works perfect, if i want to use say 20 of them, how you recommend i set the function? so i dont have to copy and paste x20

Comment: edited answer again with a possible way to handle multiple objects. From there, you can add other features like moving on vertical axis (have a propertie called 'top', starting at 0, just like we did with 'left'), change color, change the image and so on